# first time login fail on vLine

Tags: javascript, vline

I am making application on vLine

this is my source code releated with login function.

```
var client, vlinesession;var lastMsg;
var vlineClient = (function(){    
    if('{{vlineData.serviceId}}' == 'YOUR_SERVICE_ID' || '{{vlineData.serviceId}}' == 'YOUR_SERVICE_ID'){
        alert('Please make sure you have created a vLine service and that you have properly set the $serviceID and $apiSecret variables in classes/Vline.php file.');     

    }
    var authToken = '{{ vlineData.authToken }}',
        serviceId = '{{ vlineData.serviceId }}',
        profile = {"displayName": '{{ vlineData.displayName }}', "id": '{{ vlineData.id }}'};




    // Create vLine client  
    window.vlineClient = client_ = vline.Client.create({"serviceId": serviceId, "ui": true,
        'uiVideoPanel':'showvideo'
    });
    // Add login event handler

    client_.on('login', onLogin);
    client_.login(serviceId, profile, authToken).done(this.init_,this);
    // Do login
```

First time I load this javascript.

I failed to login,but then I reload it succeess.

this is the log when I failed to login.

```
 [130806 02:17:09.27] [vline.cometdTransport] AUTH_FAILED ('Login token verification failed')
 vline.js:56
 [130806 02:17:09.28] [vline.cometdTransport] FORBIDDEN ('Invalid session')
 vline.js:56
 [130806 02:17:09.30] [vline.cometdTransport] FORBIDDEN ('Invalid session') vline.js:56
 [130806 02:17:09.30] [vline.cometdTransport] FORBIDDEN ('Invalid session') vline.js:56
 [130806 02:17:09.30] [vline.cometdTransport] FORBIDDEN ('Invalid session')
```

Could you give some hints?

thanks.

Comment: Can you send an email to support@vline.com with the value of the `authToken`?

Comment: Can you do console.log(authToken) and see if it prints the same value on both first time and second time?